# Retornar uma pagina de perfil para cada usuário usando spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Olá! Estou desenvolvendo uma plataforma onde serão cadastrados alguns perfis, o objetivo é que quando esse perfil terminar o cadastro seja redirecionado para sua página de perfil com opção de editar e excluir, também preciso que esse perfil seja renderizado ao fazer logim e a pessoa possa compartilhar o perfil com outras pessoas

Esse é o controlador que controla a pagina de perfil após o login e que busca o perfil por id (pelo menos essa é a ideia).

Comecei a estudar Spring boot a pouco mais de um mes.

```
    @Controller
    public class HomeController {  

    @Autowired
    private PerfisRepo repo;

@GetMapping("/")
public String index(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, Perfil perfil) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
model.addAttribute("nome", CookieService.getCookie(request, "nomeUsuario"));
model.addAttribute(perfil.getId());
System.out.println(perfil);
return "home/index";
}

//Retorna um unici id
@RequestMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Optional<Perfil>> buscar(@PathVariable Integer id) {
Optional<Perfil> obj = repo.findById(id);
return ResponseEntity.ok().body(obj);
   }
}
```

Esse é um trexo da pagina onde os dados do perfil deveriam aparecer

```
    <div class="container-fluid">

<!-- Page Heading -->
<div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800">Olá - <span th:text="${nome}"></span> seja muito bem vindo a sua área
        Making-of</h1>
</div>
            <div>
                 <span th:text="${perfil.nomeArtistico}">Nome Artistico</span>
                 <span th:text="${email}">Email </span>
                 <span th:text="${idade}">Idade</span>
                 <span th:text="${bio}">Bio</span>
                <td><a th:href="@{'/perfis/' + ${perfil.id}}" class="btn btn-warning">Alterar</a></td>
            </div>
```

Não faço ideia de onde estou errando.

Answer (score 1):

O que ocorre é que você está retornando na requisição `@RequestMapping("/{id}")` um objeto do tipo `String`. Acredito que, como apresentado na pergunta, você deva estar utilizando um mecanismo de template, como, por exemplo, o Thymeleaf (https://www.thymeleaf.org/), percebi pelo fato de você estar utilizando a tag th (`th:text="${nome}"`).

Dessa forma, umas das formas possíveis de resolução seria você retornar um objeto do tipo ModelAndView, veja um exemplo neste link (https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html)  "Spring model attributes".

Estruturando a sua forma de resolver sua requisição, você perceberá que, dependendo da sua implementação, irá utilizar de fato uma resposta por meio do objeto `ResponseEntity` ou `String`. No entanto, o que é mais utilizado atualmente nesses momentos, é a utilização de um objeto em formato JSON (https://www.json.org/json-en.html).

Será necessário configurar o Thymeleaf para ele reconhecer o classpath da sua aplicação, que geralmente é configurada para a pasta `resources/templates/` do progeto Spring.

Você está indo muito bem no caminho, espero ter ajudado e segue o seu código com algumas modificações.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/perfil")
public class HomeController {  

    @Autowired
    private PerfilRepository perfilRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView home(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, Perfil perfil) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("/perfil/index"); // Local onde está o seu .html

        // ... 

        modelView.addAttribute("nome", CookieService.getCookie(request, "nomeUsuario"));
        modelView.addAttribute(perfil.getId());

        return modelView; // O thymeleaf será utilizado aqui pelo Spring
    }

    @RequestMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<Perfil>> buscar(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        Optional<Perfil> obj = perfilRepository.findById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(obj);
    }
}
```